# Can Command Strips be stacked for wall clearance?

Tags: hanging

I just want to know if 3M Command Strips (specifically the two-piece "velcro" type) can be stacked atop each other to provide extra ***wall clearance***.

To be clear: I am ***not*** trying to increase the weight capacity (which is what's always addressed in other answers). I ***only*** want to mount electronics (below the rated weight limit), but with greater clearance from the wall (and thereby better heat-dissipation)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: put strips on both sides of a spacer block instead of stacking strips.

Comment: Is it the sort of electronics one would normally hang from a wall? it is doubtful there was concern for adequate heat dissipation when it was designed. Command Strips work by resistance to sheer (the gravitational pull straight down from the  wall. Adding extra strips reduces the sheer resistance significantly because you increased the pull outward from the wall reducing the weight limit of the first strip.

Comment: Development boards with cases and/or screens (Raspberry Pi, Arduino, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Stacking them will give the connection more play, so it will be able to wiggle more.  It might droop a little too, and not stay straight because of the extra play.

The play in the connection could make it a bit weaker, and you mention heat dissipation, so will the command strips get warm?  That will probably weaken the bond a bit more as well.

That's all to say, that yes you can probably do this, but it will have some drawbacks, and probably won't hold much weight.  I wouldn't use it to hang anything that could fall on someone or something breakable, but if you're ok with the downsides, it could work for small, light items.

Comment: Do you think two or three industrial staples connecting the inner two (of a two-pair double stack) would affect "play"? Then it's just the two outer adhesive strips about which I have to worry since the Dual Lock should hold up if well under weight limit?

Comment: Put a cushioned chair or other "safety net" under the item. If it stays put for a few days it will likely be OK.